# String to Date in epoch time Format in Java

Tags: java, date, time, format, epoch

i have a string in a format i don't really recognize:
string received: "36872 Dec 12 15:35" 
while the windows representation for this date is: "12/12/2012 5:35 PM"

so first, I'm guessing something was corrupted in the date.
second, I'm looking to parse this string to a epoch time format

something like this: "1355371390142" (which is actually "2012-12-13 06:03:10")

Comment: coming to think about it, date format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) will be just as good as the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format `Date`s in Java like this:

```
String str = "12/12/2012 5:35 PM"; //Your String containing a date
DateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd//MM/yyyy hh:mm a"); // The mask
// 'a' value in the Mask represents AM / PM - h means hours in AM/PM mode
Date date = dF.parse(str); // parsing the String into a Date using the mask

//Date.getTime() method gives you the Long with milliseconds since Epoch.
System.out.println("Epoch representation of this date is: " + date.getTime());
```

Refer to this for mask options: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: current java date time to epoch format can get by long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
will get result as 1416306363
when convert back it to java date, by System.out.println(""+new Date(1416306836)); getting Sat Jan 17 16:55:06 SGT 1970, not current date
how its work